# Windows Account Can't See gpg Key

Tags: windows, command-line, encryption

I'm running into an issue with using a CMD.exe SSIS task and gpg.

I have created a keyring on my server while logged in as a certain user. When I want to encrypt/decrypt files within my SSIS package, everything works fine in Visual Studio - even using the execute cmd task. The problem is when I schedule a job to do the same.

When a SQL Agent job is executed, even if you execute the job as a certain user, when there is an execute command task, the line command task is executed as the service account SQL Agent is running under. In this event, the account it's running under isn't able to see MY keyring, and the encrypt task fails.

Is there a way to "point" the line command to my keyring always, or a way to make my keyring the default and grant read/execute permissions on that keyring?

The account SQL Agent runs under doesn't have its own folder under the Users file structure, so there's no way to copy a keyring to a user folder that doesn't exist I'm guessing!

Two quick things: before I get blasted for asking a stupid question, I am very new to this gpg stuff...very new, so I'm turning to this forum for guidance. Secondly, from a security standpoint, I am literally the only one who will be dealing with gpg on this server, so there won't be any issues with random users just popping on the server. It's myself and one other admin with access to the server.

Any help would be appreciated! I've also included the line command I'm executing:

```
--recipient intadmin@someplace.com --trust-model always --output "\VNUOLSERPDB1\ConcurData\Outgoing\EVI_p006320452r3_20170208.txt.pgp" --encrypt "\VNUOLSERPDB1\ConcurData\Outgoing\EVI_p006320452r3_20170208.txt"
```

Comment: I should add tat the account SQL Server Agent runs under is NT\SQLSERVERAGENT and it DOES look like there is a user account folder for this account. When looking at the gnupg folder, there is a pubring.gpg file and a secring.gpg file.  So I guess my question would be how do I "export" the pubring.gpg file in my user folder to the folder for this service account? I've looked around and I can only see an option to export a single key. I tried that and the job still could not find the public key. Just the actual .asc file was exported to the gnupg directory for the SQLSERVERAGENT account.

Comment: Your command line is missing a command :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this same line command runs fine when I run in within the context of Visual Studio. What line command is actually missing?

Comment: The bit before `--recipient`!

Comment: The bit before --recipient?? Doesn't really help...sorry

Comment: `--recipient` -> `'--recipient' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed similar issue today:

moved files from C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\
to C:\Users\SQLServerAgentUserName\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\

then inserted the following option in gpg command
--homedir C:\Users\SQLServerAgentUserName\AppData\Roaming\gnupgoption 
before the --encrypt option

Comment: Thanks, Paul!!!! That did it!!!! Would have been spinning my wheels forever on this one!